# probability of liminf of a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I wonder what's the difference between the probability below.(maybe (1) is greater than (2)?)

---

P($\varliminf_{n \to \infty} {x<\epsilon}$), note (1) and

---

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(x<\epsilon)$, note (2)

Comment: Do you know Fatou's Lemma?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Fatou's Lemma. I will google them to see how it works on this one.

Comment: Does Fatou's lemma indicate that (1) is greater or equal to (2)?

Comment: (1) less than or equal to (2).

Comment: I have checked Fatou's lemma. I find that it is true if (2) is liminf. Does it mean that (2) is greater than or equal to liminf of P(x<$\epsilon$)?

Comment: Of course, $lim P(x<\epsilon)$ need not exist. In general (1) is less than or equal to $\lim \inf P(x<\epsilon)$ but if the limit exists we can say that (1) is less than or equal to (2).  BTW you should indicate the dependence of $x$ on $n$ by writing $x_n$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot!